# How to correct implement the Repository Adapter?

Tags: typescript, backend, nestjs, typeorm, clean-architecture

I started learning how to build Clean Architecture based on TypeScript and NestJS. Everything was ok until I started implementing the Repository Adapter and Controllers. The main problem is incompatible return types for the API methods and use-cases.

The idea was to put entities and use-cases in the **core** folderin which use-cases use repository adapter (through DI). This adapter implements the repository interface from the **core** folder too.

Implementation of the repository adapter contains in **app**. **app** also contains NestJS implementation, TypeOrm entities etc. But also I want to use a repository for some controllers like `getAll query`.

**!!!AND THE PROBLEM!!!**

For almost every command, I have to use `Mappers` because TypeORM entity and Domain Entity are incompatible types. And I think that's okay if we pass that data to the use-case because we need to transform data from TypeOrm shape to the domain shape.

But if I just call the repository adapter method in the controller I need to map data back again... And I don't know how to skip unnecessary steps.
In my imagination, I can just call the repository method in **app** service, and that is it.
And if I skip the mapping back then all data properties will have the prefix `_`(

Maybe someone met the same problem?

//CORE ZONE

Account entity (`/domain/account`):

```
export type AccountId = string;
export class Account {
constructor(
  private readonly _id: AccountId,
  private readonly _firstName: string
) {}

  get id(): AccountId {
   return this._id;
  }

  get firstName() {
   return this._firstName;
  }
}
```

Repository interface (`repositories/account-repository`):

```
import { Account } from '../domains/account';

export interface AccountRepository {
  getAccountById(id: string): Promise<Account>;
  getAllAccounts(): Promise<Account[]>;
}
```

Example of use-case with repositoty:

```
import { AccountRepository } from '../../repositories/account-repository';

export class ToDoSomething {
  constructor(private readonly _accountRepository: AccountRepository) {}

  async doSomethingWithAccount(command): Promise<boolean> {
    const account = await this._accountRepository.getAccountById(
      command.accountId,
    );

    if (!account) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

//APP ZONE

Repository Adapter:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Account } from '../../../../core/domains/account';
import { AccountRepository } from '../../../../core/repositories/account-repository';
import { AccountEntity } from '../account.entity';
import { AccountMapper } from '../account.mapper';

@Injectable()
export class AccountRepositoryAdapter implements AccountRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(AccountEntity)
    private readonly _accountRepository: Repository<AccountEntity>,
  ) {}

  async getAccountById(id: string): Promise<Account> {
    return this._accountRepository.findOne({ id: id });
    // will return { id: 1, firstName: "name" }
    // and because I need to use MapToDomain
  }

  async getAllAccounts(): Promise<Account[]> {
    return this._accountRepository.find();
    // Here too I need to use MapToDomain for every item
  }
}
```

TypeOrm Account:

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ name: 'account' })
export class AccountEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Clean Architecture the control and data flow is usually like this: controller takes request from view (e.g. web app) and converts it into a request model which is than passed to the use case. The use case reads from the request model what it should compute and uses repository to interact with domain entities to finally create a response model. The response model is then passed to presenter (which might be same class as controller) which converts this into a response for the view.

The controller usually does not interact with domain entities or even ORM types.

Check out my blog series on implementing Clean Architecture for more details: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Controller-Presenter/

Comment: Great. I've thought I'm doing extra steps with data mapping. But anyway we should form Request data to Domain form. And of course, need to form back. We don't have another way.
Can you suggest creating the use-case for almost every API call? Like GET:/get-all- users and etc. The reason why I got this question is. Should we convert every item in the list if we don't need to do some domain logic? Because in my point of view we can avoid it, but I don't know how to do it..( Maybe we can skip the convert to Domain model and immediately pass data to the Presenter. And of course, that is correct?

Comment: As to my experience "short cuts" are ok in the beginning of the project or when there is almost no logic needed for respond to a request. Over time projects usually get more complex and then short cuts should be removed and then really every request will us use cases.